# Are there Chinese language-learning karaoke videos at a basic conversation level?

Tags: learning, resources

I noticed that watching karaoke videos accelerates learning Chinese characters, even though you might not understand the characters fully. Is there a list of Mandarin and Cantonese karaoke videos for kids to learn characters?

Answer (score 1):

Karaoke is more like combining the MV and lyrics together, most of them afford the instrumental version, which means that you can find them in Music Company. Of course, there is a faster way, if you know a karaoke store owner, he/she know how to get you a list of karaoke.

FYI -
Most karaoke videos are properties of music companies, but due to some reasons lots of people have access to the pirate. So you might need to be cautious to avoid the legal issue.

Comment: I'm sure someone has it up on youtube or youku. I just cant type or read chinese to find them.

Comment: @Patoshi Of course in YouTube and Youku, but you could never found a complete list of karaoke. Most lists are grouped by some elements like the poublic year, style, singer, etc....

Answer (score 0):

> I'm sure someone has it up on youtube or youku. I just cant type or
>   read chinese to find them.  – Patoshi パトシ

Keywords:  `卡拉ok` for karaoke and `粵語` for Cantonese

Search for `卡拉ok` on Youtube will get results mainly in Mandarin.

p.s. I believe this answer should be in the comment section, but my reputation(31) is too low to do so.

Comment: Please be more specific and answer the question of the original poster.